# Plugin application hangs when invoking functionality from another DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I am trying to render a GStreamer pipeline running on top of a XUL window.

For this I wrote an XPCOM plugin. A XPCOM plugin is basically a dll file that gets loaded by the Gecko engine. My plugin links with GStreamer and as a consequence it depends on many other GStreamer plugins (also dll files).

Invoking GStreamer code (for example a simple function like `gst_pipeline_new`) causes the application to crash. More specifically it freezes and hangs in glib consuming an entire CPU core (50% of total CPU):

[image]

Would someone be willing to help me figure out what's going wrong?

**Edit**

A few remarks:

- Stand-alone GStreamer projects on Windows work fine.
- The XUL plugin works fine as well (as long as I don't make any GStreamer calls).
- From within the XUL plugin I can call a simple glib functions like g_strndup without any problems.
- Calling GStreamer functions from within the plugin crashes the app.

This code can reproduce the problem. (I'm not sure if it's helpful though..)

The plugin .idl file defines the property `videoWindow`:

```
#include "nsISupports.idl"
interface nsIDOMXULElement;

[scriptable, uuid(BFE3F1BF-1C7B-4da2-8EAB-12F7683FAF71)]
interface IVideo : nsISupports
{
  attribute nsIDOMXULElement videoWindow;
};
```

Its implementation can reproduce the problem:

```
NS_IMETHODIMP Video::SetVideoWindow(nsIDOMXULElement * inXULVideoWindow)
{
    GstElement * pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("test"); // freezes here
    return NS_OK;
}
```

**Edit**
Problem is fixed. See my own answer to this post.

Comment: This could be due to any number of reasons - back recursion, stack corruption, race condition - try narrowing the problem, or at least show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm embarrased... I forgot to execute the GStreamer initialization function:

```
gst_init(NULL, NULL);
```

Problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your symbols so that you can read the gstreamer and glib functions - this may require compiling these two libraries from source. Once you see the real stack, solving the problem will be **much** easier.